# change background color when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have written code which shows morning and evening times, the code is working fine,but the issue is that, say when I select a time by clicking, I want only that time's `background-color` to be changed and not of all.

For example, first I select 9:30, then 9:30 should be selected with a background color, again If I select 10:00 then previously selected 9:30's selected background color should disappear and the corresponding color should be applied to 10:00.

can anyone please tell me some solution for this?

My code is as given below

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f2vLfxfu/)**

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="box col-md-6" style="width: 40%;height: 100%;  !important;padding-left: 15px;">
                <div class="ibox float-e-margins datetimepicker1 table-responsive">
                    <div class="ibox-content">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-4 b-r" style="text-align: center;">
                                 <h3 class="m-t-none m-b"><b>Morning</b></h3>

                                <div class="m-t-none m-b sm-time" ng-class="{'selected': timeClass}" ng-click="timeClass=true">9:00AM</div>
                                <div class="m-t-none m-b sm-time" ng-class="{'selected': timeClass}" ng-click="timeClass=true">9:30AM</div>
                                <div class="m-t-none m-b sm-time" ng-class="{'selected': timeClass}" ng-click="timeClass=true">10:00AM</div>
                                <div class="m-t-none m-b sm-time" ng-class="{'selected': timeClass}" ng-click="timeClass=true">10:30AM</div>
                                <div class="m-t-none m-b sm-time" ng-class="{'selected': timeClass}" ng-click="timeClass=true">11:00AM</div>
                                <div class="m-t-none m-b sm-time" ng-class="{'selected': timeClass}" ng-click="timeClass=true">11:30AM</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                 <h3 class="m-t-none m-b"><center><b>Afternoon</b></center></h3>

                                <div class="col-md-12" style="text-align: center;">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                                            <div class="m-t-none m-b sm-time "  ng-class="{'selected': timeClass}" ng-click="timeClass=true">9:30AM</div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                                            <div class="m-t-none m-b sm-time" ng-class="{'selected': timeClass}" ng-click="timeClass=true">9:30AM</div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                                            <div class="m-t-none m-b sm-time" ng-class="{'selected': timeClass}" ng-click="timeClass=true">9:00AM</div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                                            <div class="m-t-none m-b sm-time" ng-class="{'selected': timeClass}" ng-click="timeClass=true">9:30AM</div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                                            <div class="m-t-none m-b sm-time" ng-class="{'selected': timeClass}" ng-click="timeClass=true">9:00AM</div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                                            <div class="m-t-none m-b sm-time" ng-class="{'selected': timeClass}" ng-click="timeClass=true">9:30AM</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm asking **if jQuery is allowed**. If yes, then solution will be easy.

Comment: yes we are also using jquery.....

Comment: I posted a non-jQuery, easy and short answer below.

Comment: For confirmation - Is this static or you are using ng-repeat to print times?

Comment: time beign I have placed a static code in jsfiddle, but in my real code I am using ng-repeat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check working example [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f2vLfxfu/19/)

Controller

```
app.controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.morningTimes =['8.00AM','9.00AM','9.30AM','10.00AM','10.40AM'];
    $scope.selectedDate = '';

    $scope.setIndex = function(index) {
        $scope.selectedDate = index;
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="m-t-none m-b sm-time" ng-class="{'selected':selectedDate == $index}" ng-click="setIndex($index)" ng-repeat="time in morningTimes">{{time}}</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using ng-repeat would be best. However if you want to go ahead with static way instead of using ng-repeat you can make a directive. Here is the jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/tech_ank/f2vLfxfu/16/

```
app.directive('whenClick', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, iElement, iAttr) {
            iElement.on("click", function () {

                iElement.parent().children().removeClass('selected');
                iElement.addClass('selected');
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should create your times using `ng-repeat` by creating a *scope array* in your *controller*:

```
$scope.morningtimes = [
    {time: '9:00AM', selected: true},
    {time: '9:30AM', selected: false},
    {time: '10:00AM', selected: false},
    {time: '10:30AM', selected: false},
    {time: '11:00AM', selected: false},
    {time: '11:30AM', selected: false},
];
```

Then add something like this to your *template*:

```
<div class="m-t-none m-b sm-time" ng-repeat="time in morningtimes" ng-class="{'selected': time.selected}" ng-click="setSelected($index)">{{time.time}}</div>
```

As you can see, each object has its time and a `selected` *attribute*. Plus, it triggers a *function* `setSelection($index)` on click, which will reset all *array objects* and sets the right one (based on its index) to *true*:

```
$scope.setSelected = function(index) {
    angular.forEach($scope.morningtimes, function(item) {
        item.selected = false;
    })
    $scope.morningtimes[index].selected = true;
}
```

Everything together: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f2vLfxfu/12/)

Answer (score 0):

You should move some logic to the controller instead of the template. I updated your fiddle with a solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/5rkddz0u/1/

Controller:

```
$scope.changeHighlight = function(time) {
    $scope.highlightedTime = time;
}

$scope.highlightedTime = undefined;

$scope.morningTimes = ["9:00AM", "9:30AM","10:00AM","10:30AM","11:00AM","11:30AM"];

$scope.afternoonTimes = ["12:30PM", "13:00PM","13:30PM","14:00PM"];
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="time in morningTimes" class='m-t-none m-b sm-time' ng-class="{'selected':highlightedTime === time}" ng-click="changeHighlight(time)">{{time}}</div>
```

Basically we're moving the times to display to the controller, and using ng-repeat in the template to display them.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but the issue is your answer is that say  I select 9:30 then it should be green, after that when I select another time say 10:00 then the green background color which was previously given to 9:30 should disappear and 10:00 should get that green background color

Comment: BackgroundColor of previous selected elements not disappearing.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood your question then. Let me check on it quickly.

Comment: at a time one time should be selected and should have green background

Comment: @Alex Man: I updated my fiddle to have one at a time selected :)

Answer (score 0):

using jQuery solution is simple: [see this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f2vLfxfu/15/). Code is this:

```
jQuery(document).ready( function () {

jQuery('.sm-time').click(function () {
 jQuery('.sm-time').removeClass('selected');
 jQuery(this).addClass('selected');
});
```